# Cypher Query Language/Neo4j - Nested Returns of Variable Path Length

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph structure in Neo4j for a questionnaire that has the following relationships:

```
    (a:Category)-[:INITIAL_QUESTION]->(b:Question)-[c:Answer*]->(d:Question)
```

where the specific question text is contained in `(b|d).text` and the possible answers for each question is contained in the relationship `c.response`
From the initial question, there are some paths that are longer than others. I would like the return to look something like this:

```
{"category": "example questionnaire category",
"initialQuestion" : {
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "Example text here",
                    "possibleAns": {
                      "yes" : {
                                "id": 2,
                                "text": "Second question text here?",
                                "possibleAns": {
                                                  "ans1": {/*Question 4 containing all possible child question nodes nested
                                                              in possibleAns*/},
                                                  "ans2": {/*Question 5 containing all possible child question nodes nested
                                                              in possibleAns*/},
                                }
                      },
                      "no" :{
                                "id": 3,
                                "text": "Different question text here?",
                                "possibleAns": {
                                                  "ans1": {/*Question 6 containing all possible child question nodes nested
                                                              in possibleAns*/},
                                                  "ans2": {/*Question 7 containing all possible child question nodes nested
                                                              in possibleAns*/},
                                }
                      }
                    }
 }
}
```

so that the entire category questionnaire is contained in a single, nested map. I've seen some other examples, but haven't been able to tweak those queries to fit my needs, especially given the variable depth of the questionnaire branches.

Is there a Cypher query that makes this possible? If not, what would be the best approach for retrieving the entire questionnaire from the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is not done with standard tools (cypher etc.)

So, or transform the result from cypher query in the json-tree programmatically.

Or, if your neo4j-server versions not less 3.0, you can try [`apoc.convert.toTree`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_from_tojson):

```
MATCH path = (a:Category)
             -[:INITIAL_QUESTION]->(b:Question)-[c:Answer*]->
             (d:Question)
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value as tree
RETURN tree
```